# Prove or disprove: For non-negative integers $m$ and $n$, $m!n! = (mn)!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, factorial

I have rewritten the question as "If $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers, then $m!n!$ = $(mn)!$"

Here is my current attempt. I am not sure if I am on the right path.

Proof. 
Let $m$ and $n$ be non-negative integers. 
So $m! = (m-1)! * m, n! = (n-1)! * n$, and $m!n! = mn(m-1)!(n-1)!$. 
On the other hand, $(mn)! = (mn - 1)! * mn$. 
... 
Therefore, $m!n! = (mn)!$.

Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: You are not.  What is $2!3!$?  What is $(2 \cdot 3)!$?

Comment: obviously when one of m and n is greater than one, then you don't have (mn)!=m!n!..

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. I must have made a multiplication error when I tried finding a counterexample earlier, I just caught it as this was answered. Sorry! How embarrassing!

Comment: Why don't you answer your own question in order to close the question?

Comment: Note that the fault in your proof is that you are using the induction principle in an unjustified way. In the calculation of $m!n!$ you increase both $m$ and $n$ by one, but in the calculation of $(mn)!$, you only increase one of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @Ben You mean, if **both** $m$ and $n$ are greater than one, then you don't have $(mn)!=m!n!$. If $m\gt1$ and $n=1$ then $(mn)!=m!n!=m!$.

Answer (score 1):

This statement can be disproven.

Counterexample.
Let $m = 0$ and $n = 5$. 
So $m!n! = 0! * 5! = 1*5*4*3*2*1 = 120$. 
On the other hand, $(mn)! = (0 * 5)! = 0! = 1$. 
$120 ≠ 1$. 
Therefore, $m!n! ≠ (mn)!$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $m, n > 1$ then $m!n! < m!(m + 1).....(m + n) = (m + n)! \le (mn)!$.